# how to allow remote access of mysql and test the connection (Centos 7)

Tags: php, mysql, centos7

I have already followed the following link to setup the MySQL server in CentOS 7.
[How to allow remote connection to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)

However, by commenting out 
*"bind-address = XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"* in /etc/my.cnf
, it does not work at all. 
the mariadb cannot be restarted.
*systemctl restart mariadb*

Should I work on firewall setting or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the firewall problem.
I have tick the service mysql in the public zone in firewall setting.
However, I don't know if this is a "safe" practice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the sql  user permission. Each SQL user has a "scope". By default, all user are authorized from "localhost". You have to create a new SQL user with "%" as client.

Comment: hi Thibault, Thanks for  your reply. I know where is the problem. It is due to the firewall. Now, I tick the mysql service in public zone... Then I can connect to mysql server now. However, I don't know if this is a safe practice...ask for your comment.

Comment: If you have a good firewall, allow the MySQL connexion only for you distant IP, not for everyone.

Comment: Actually, I just allow my home IP to access the mariadb database in my office. I have set the privileges for that home IP only. Is it enough?